# How can I disable a jQuery function from running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mouseover

I am working on a balloon coloring program.

I have some jQuery functions that trade out the balloon images.
When the page opens the the white balloons at the bottom can be colored one at a time or if you hit the roller button you can mouse-over and color them all at once.
I would like to click the off button to stop the roller function but to be able to start it again if needed.

I have tried timers and just about everything else and I have not found anything that works.
The code is in the link above. Thank you in advance!

```js
var colorNow = "https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/1.png";

$(".balloons").click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).attr('src', colorNow);
})

var $palette = $("#palette");
$palette.click(function(event) {
  $color = $(event.target);
  colorNow = $color.attr('src');
})

function Roller() {
  var colorNow = "https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/1.png";
  $(".balloons").mouseover(function(event) {
    $(event.target).attr('src', colorNow);
  })
  var $palette = $("#palette");
  $palette.click(function(event) {
    $color = $(event.target);
    colorNow = $color.attr('src');
  })
}

function clearRoller() {
  //???????????????
  // I need script to remove or disable the Roller function
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="balloons">
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 20px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 60px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 100px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 140px;"></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 180px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 220px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 260px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 300px;" title=""></div>
</div>
<div id="palette">
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/1.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 20px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 60px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/3.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/4.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 140px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/5.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 180px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/6.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 220px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/7.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 260px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/8.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 300px;" title=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you embed the code you are concerned about? Never mind, I embedded it. But your image links will break in the future, I suggest you upload the images here to be stored on the SE imgur server.

Comment: Don't you mean `$(".balloons div img").click`? To further-explain, you should probably make the balloon classes have a background image and use a sprite-sheet to hold all the balloon images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this? I just changed mouseover to "on" - works with dynamic elements.
Function for roller button now only toggling "roller" class for "balloons" class element.

EDIT: Mr. Polywhirl made much more elegant work here, .off is also better for performance, than always active event listener.

https://jsfiddle.net/chada090/gvr8o5b9/2

```
var colorNow = "https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/1.png";

$(".balloons").click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).attr('src', colorNow);
})

var $palette = $("#palette");
$palette.click(function(event) {
  $color = $(event.target);
  colorNow = $color.attr('src');
})
$("body").on("mouseover",".balloons.roller",function(event) {
    $(event.target).attr('src', colorNow);
})

function Roller() {
  $(".balloons").toggleClass("roller");
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="balloons">
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 20px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 60px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 100px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 140px;"></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 180px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 220px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 260px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 300px;" title=""></div>
</div>
<div id="palette">
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/1.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 20px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/2.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 60px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/3.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/4.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 140px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/5.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 180px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/6.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 220px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/7.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 260px;" title=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://balloonmaster.com/color-change/latex/8.png" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 300px;" title=""></div>
</div>
<button onclick="Roller()">roller</button>
```

Comment: Thank You Chada, I like having all the new options and it helps me to understand just a little bit more how to structure my coding.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting a background image for the balloons and keeping each as a single div. That way you know when you clicked on it and you can grab data directly off of it too.

You can add a check-box to determine if you are in a roll-over state to add or remove the listener.

```js
let currentColor = null;

const handleRollOver = (event) => {
  $(event.target).attr('data-color', currentColor); // set color
};

$('.palette .balloon').click((e) => {
  $('.palette .balloon').removeClass('balloon-active');
  currentColor = $(e.target).addClass('balloon-active').attr('data-color'); // get color
});

$('.canvas .balloon').click((e) => {
  $(e.target).attr('data-color', currentColor); // set color
});

$('.mode-roller').on('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    $('.canvas .balloon').on('mouseover', handleRollOver); // enable
  } else {
    $('.canvas .balloon').off('mouseover', handleRollOver); // disable
  }
});
```

```css
body { padding: 0.5em; font-size: smaller; }
body h1 { margin-top: 0.25em; }

.balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ4i3.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background-size: 10em;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.balloon:hover { cursor: pointer; }

.balloon[data-color="black"]  { background-position:  0.0em   0.0px; }
.balloon[data-color="white"]  { background-position: -2.5em   0.0px; }
.balloon[data-color="red"]    { background-position: -5.0em   0.0px; }
.balloon[data-color="orange"] { background-position: -7.5em   0.0px; }
.balloon[data-color="yellow"] { background-position:  0.0em  -2.5em; }
.balloon[data-color="green"]  { background-position: -2.5em  -2.5em; }
.balloon[data-color="blue"]   { background-position: -5.0em  -2.5em; }
.balloon[data-color="violet"] { background-position: -7.5em  -2.5em; }

.balloon-active { background-color: #DD7; }

form { border: thin solid grey; padding: 0.33em; margin-top: 0.667em; }
form h2 {margin-top: 0.25em; }
.form-field label { display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Balloon Roller</h1>
<div class="palette">
  <div class="balloon" data-color="black"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="red"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="orange"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="yellow"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="green"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="blue"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="violet"></div>
</div>
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="balloon" data-color="white"></div>
</div>
<form>
  <h2>Options</h2>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label>Roller Mode</label> <input type="checkbox" class="mode-roller">
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Also, I created a spritesheet from your images which is available here:

> [image: spritesheet]

Comment: Mr Polywhirl, You are so awesome!
This is way more info than I dreamed of getting.
I am so appreciative for all that you shared here.
I have considered sprites but did not know how to go about using them.
I also wanted to know about backgrounds and you have given examples as well. I am new to coding. My world fell apart when flash died. I am trying to learn all I can to replace my old programs. This opens up the world to me.
Thank You!!!!! 